# How to resolve with Unity in .NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

Using Unity in a Web API project, I have registered an object (type `MyService` implementing `IMyService`) in a UnityContainer the standard way.

```
public static class UnityConfig {
    public static void RegisterComponents() {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

        // Register my type
        container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
}
```

I resolve the object in one of my classes like this (it's not a controller so I can't use constructor injection):

```
// Get object from container
var myService = (IMyService)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver
                    .GetService(typeof(IMyService));
```

**Is that the correct way?** It seems so clunky. Is there a more succinct way to make this call, such as accessing the container's `Resolve<T>()` method directly?

(I may be splitting hairs here but I'm new to using Unity with Web API and trying to understand the best practices.)

Comment: For non controllers, why not just keep the instance in a static(singleton) and access it from there?

Comment: Where are you calling the code from? You say it's a non-controller. Is it a service? Where is it used?

Comment: This code is in a custom attribute that I have created, which complicates matters. I'm happy with Spock's answer (in short, I should rely on dependency injection instead of calling the DependencyResolver directly), however it turns out Unity can't inject into attributes (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677029/injecting-class-into-authentication-attribute-using-unity-2-and-mvc-3) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121050/mvc-3-unity-2-inject-dependencies-into-a-filter)), so my choices are to keep my code as-is or implement a custom FilterAttributeFilterProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is that the right way"?

Generally speaking if you are using proper DI principals the answer is No.
What you doing is asking the DependencyResolver to resolve the service IMyService. 
This is also known as [Hollywood Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle): don't call the container; it'will call you.

This is also no different to asking the Unity Container to resolve the IMyService. 
i.e
Container.Resolve

The best approach is to use proper Constructor Injection, if not property Injection or some of the designated injection patterns
https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns

If your DEPENDENCY requires injecting more than often in many classes you may also consider using an Ambient Container. But this is unlikely the case.
[What is the meaning of the word ambient in this comment from CommonServiceLocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235461/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-ambient-in-this-comment-from-commonservicelocato)

Also notice that your class that consumes the DependencyResolver is using DI technique i.e .Resolve which is not visiable by the out side of the class. 
This also means the component cannot be reuse as the outside world would not know for sure what DI it requires at compile time. If the DI requires is not registered then can cause runtime error (if the DEPENDENCY has not been registered).